# Pass a list of OrderedDicts from validated_data to **kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

with a `ModelSerializer` I needed to pass multiple generic relations and it works well. However, I need to recreate many for loops within the update/create methods for it work how could I pass them as **kwargs in a function since the outcome is a list of OrederedDicts?

For instance I have two models:

models.py:

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    """
    Model that stores all translations
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=5, db_index=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, null=True)
    translation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class Tags(models.Model):
    """
        Tags Model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    DISEASE = 0
    TYPE = [(DISEASE, 'disease')]
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE)
    name = GenericRelation(Translation)  # < ------- 
    description = GenericRelation(Translation) # < -------
```

serializer.py:

```
class TranslationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ 
    Translation serializer to be nested into other
    serializers that needs to display their translation.
    """
    # id added to be used on create/update query only
    # since it is not instantiated.
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Translation

        """
        Fields:
        object_id and content_type are not required 
        and are passed dynamically.

        Uncomment if needed.
        """
        fields = ["id","lang","translation","field"]

class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    """ 
    Tag serializer with generic relation to field 'name' and 'description'.
    """

    name = TranslationSerializer(required=False, many=True)
    description = TranslationSerializer(required=False, many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['id', 'type', 'name','description']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.type =  validated_data.get('type', instance.type)
        instance.save()
        # values that need to be passed dynamically for a full-behavioral function.
        names_data = validated_data.pop('name')
        descriptions_data = validated_data.pop('description')

        model = self.Meta.model
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
        # gets total value from names_data and loops its values.
        name_items_dicts = [i for i in names_data]
        description_items_dicts = [i for i in descriptions_data]

        # FOR LOOPS FOR name FIELD <------- 1st time for name field.
        for name in names_data:
            name_id = name.get('id', None)
            name_field = name.get('field', None)

            if name_id and name_field == 'name':
                name_item = Translation.objects\
                    .get(id=name_id, object_id=instance)
                name_item.lang = name.get('lang', name_item.lang)
                name_item.translation = \
                    name.get('translation', name_item.translation)
                name_item.save()

            else:
                # create
                name['content_type'] = content_type
                name['object_id'] = instance
                # find how to dynamically add field name here
                name['field'] = 'name'
                Translation.objects.update_or_create(**name)

        for other_name in names_data:
            name_from_db = Translation.objects.\
                filter(object_id=instance, field=other_name['field'])
            name_from_db_to_compare = name_from_db.count()

            if  name_id and name_field == 'name' and\
                 name_from_db_to_compare > len(name_items_dicts):
                name_from_db.delete()
                other_name['id'] = None
                other_name['content_type'] = content_type
                other_name['object_id'] = instance
                # find how to dynamically add field name here
                other_name['field'] = 'name'
                Translation.objects.update_or_create(**other_name)

        # FOR LOOPS FOR description FIELD <------- 2nd time for description field.
        for description in descriptions_data:
            description_id = description.get('id', None)
            description_field = description.get('field', None)
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
           
            if  description_id and description_field == 'description' and\
                 description_from_db_to_compare > len(description_items_dicts):
            ... # all the functionality done again for the descrioption field here...

        return instance
```

As you can see above I am going against the DRY standards I need to create everything again for each field that has a relation with the translation.

I have tried to pass them as kwargs but with no success:

```
def translation_update_field(self, **kwargs):

    model = self.Meta.model
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model)
    # gets total value from _data and loops its values.
    arg_items_dicts = [i for i in kwargs]

    for arg in kwargs:
        arg_id = arg.get('id', None)
        arg_field = arg.get('field', None)
        
        if arg_id and arg_field == 'name':
            arg_item = Translation.objects.get(id=arg_id, object_id=instance)
            arg_item.lang = arg.get('lang', arg_item.lang)
         ... 

def update(self, instance, validate_data):

      names_data = validated_data.pop('name')
      descriptions_data = validated_data.pop('description')
    
    translation_update_field(self, names_data, descriptions_data):
        # values passed as list of OrderedDicts not need to create the funcionality for each..
        ...
```

Error:

```
TypeError: translation_update_field() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

What I would like to apply is pass the for loops into the `translation_update_field()` function to be able to pass the translations to other classes and not need to add massive repeaded code into the serializers.

Comment: Play around with this code snippet: `
def f(a, **kwargs):
    print(a, kwargs)

dict={'b': 1, 'c': 'test'}
dict2={2, 'z'}

f(3, **dict)
f(4, **dict2)
f(5, x=1, z=2)
`

Comment: [args and kwargs explained](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev I will try to apply this approach to OrederedDict. I really appreciated your help.